# no styling on the headers in redactor wysiwyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg, redactor, redactor.js

The problem is that I cannot convert the **header** into `italics` or `strike` or `bold`. I even tried this in their [official redactor website](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) but the problem still persist. I can only change it (the **header**) to `italics` (or other styles) if I first change it into a normal text. Is this the expected behavior or a bug? I really need a solution regarding this matter. Thank you.

**Update:**

The version of Redactor that I am using is 10.23 (latest).

Comment: Check out the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088397/can-i-customise-the-header-tagsh1-h2-h3-in-redactor-editor/34276847#34276847

Answer (score 0):

They do not allow to format the headers, but you can [add custom formatting tags](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/formatting-add/).

Hope it helps